# Spellcasting while Poisoned

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, conditions

So this question came up while working on magic items. The "poisoned" condition is used as a general catch-all for being/feeling sick, not just that you got a dose of poison (most of which don't actually give the condition).
Poisoned gives disadvantage on attacks and ability checks. While RAW this would likely apply to spells that make an attack roll, there is no mention of any other spellcasting, which seems kinda left out, as something mentally difficult especially when you don't feel good at all.

Does anyone else do something with this? Add an additional con save for casting/concentration?

Comment: What game and edition are you playing? Further, it isn't clear what you are asking. Are you just asking for ideas about what you can add to the poisoned condition? We don't really handle "ideas" questions like that.

Comment: Sorry, I intended DnD 5e, but it would apply to any system that uses the poisoned condition. Question is more on how the rules seem to apply the condition differently to spellcasting than they do to regular attacks and ability stuff.
But yes, it was more an idea question than RAW specific.

Comment: It definitely does not apply to any system, different systems have different rules. "Does anyone else do something with this" seems like your more just asking for house rule ideas, which we don't handle.

Comment: "poison conditions" are something that is handled differently in *many different* games. In Shadowrun 4, you repeatedly have to resist direct damage to your health track a set amount of times. In World of Darkness, some splats are plainly immune to poison, and most poisons just apply damage (which you can resist) till you can somehow end that condition. In some systems you just plainly take damage and can't prevent that, or end poison early. That is entirely different from how poison is handled in DnD 5e.